# Crystal Reports not sending parameters to Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle11g, crystal-reports-xi

I have a new Crystal Report, starting from our company's standard template, which has two connections: one to get some header information and then the Oracle stored procedure.  When I run the report, only data for the header shows.  That means the connection is working.

When I do a Show SQL Query, I can see the second query is not sending any parameters to Oracle:

```
OraDB
SELECT * 
  FROM HeaderInfo RPT
  WHERE RPT_NUM = 'RPT829'


OraDB
BEGIN "OraUser"."Proc_829"(:CRYSTAL_CURSOR, NULL, NULL, NULL); END ;
```

I've entered the parameters, but there is a linkage missing somewhere, because it's just NULLs here.  Where do I set that?

I have tried re-creating the report, starting from the same template, and it does not work.  I have started a new report, adding my parameter first and then the command for the header, and it does.  It just works, and binding those variables isn't something that is normally done manually.  But when the binding doesn't work, is there a way to force it?

In my field explorer, it has the following:

> ```
> - Database Fields
> .....+ Proc_829
> .....+ Command
> + Formula Fields
> - Parameter Fields
> .....Divisions
> .....StartDate
> .....EndDate
> ```

When I refresh, it asks for those parameters, which match the parameters that the Proc_829 needs.  But it shows no data (the proc runs in Oracle and returns data with those same parameters), and the Show SQL Query, as above, is sending nulls.

The standard is to avoid the use of a subreport, and start with this template.  The template was changed recently, but I've used previous iterations and it has worked.  The template has the Command and some header information already added, and common parameter fields, which happen to match what my procedure needs.

**Edit**  Here is the opening (obfuscated) part of the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_829 (
   CRYSTAL_CURSOR  IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
   ,Divisions       IN  VARCHAR2
   ,StartDate       IN  DATE
   ,EndDate         IN  DATE
) IS
  -- bunch of stuff here, including
OPEN crystal_cursor FOR
  -- my select stuff that returns data in Oracle
```

Comment: Look sir, it is very hard for me to downvote a post by an immensely experienced person like you, but I have to. As I read it, all you need to do is find a method to bind your input variables into your procedures. There are methods to do it and all of them are easily found over the Internet. Where have you looked, sir?

Comment: Have you ever try `subreports` in crystalreport? i think that you can solve the problem with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're supposed to avoid subreports if at all possible.  Crystal complains, but two unrelated queries/procedures are what we're supposed to use.

Comment: @Rachcha ok, I've spent several more days looking, also asked co-workers, and trying various things.  All I have is an Oracle procedure I'm using in Crystal Reports.  If I start a new report, I add the procedure and it just links, CR knows what parameters are needed for the proc.  It's not making that link, and in spite of how easy you say it is to find, I'm finding information on c# linking and viewing the sql.  But nothing on what to do when the proc parameters just are not there.  Starting over with that template has also not worked, and a version of it has worked in the past.

Comment: Are you sure that those `NULL`s are not hardcoded? Could you post some sample code for us to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Rachcha hardcoded where?  (I think that would answer my question.)  The only code is the Oracle procedure, and I can post the opening part of that.

Comment: Hardcoded where CR calls the Oracle stored procedure- `BEGIN "OraUser"."Proc_829"(:CRYSTAL_CURSOR, NULL, NULL, NULL); END ;`. There is one bind variable `:CRYSTAL_CURSOR` to which CR would bind a cursor. The other parameters, are they hardcoded to null?

Comment: @Rachcha Show SQL Query is a read-only view of how Crystal is calling the linked procedures.  Since it can't be edited there, my question is where can it be edited?  Maybe it is hardcoded to null, but if so, where in Crystal is that changed?  When I refresh the report, I do enter values (which oddly, do not have a checkbox to set them to null).

Comment: @Rachcha I have also completely deleted my parameter fields, then added my procedure and then added them back.  I'm starting to think our template is messed up in some subtle way, and that this is an unanswerable question.